# Calculation for start and end dates of the month are incorrect

Tags: objective-c, ios8, nsdate

I have this code that is supposed to compute the start and end date of a month (the dates are used in a NSPredicate to search a CoreData store for records between the start of the month and the end of the month)

```
    NSDate *startOfMonth;
    NSDate *endOfMonth;
    NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval interval;

    [cal rangeOfUnit:NSMonthCalendarUnit startDate:&startOfMonth interval:&interval forDate:now];
    endOfMonth = [startOfMonth dateByAddingTimeInterval:interval-1];
    NSLog(@"\n\nstartOfMonth: %@\nendOfMonth: %@\ninterval: %f",startOfMonth, endOfMonth, interval);
```

This is the output from the NSLog:

```
startOfMonth: 2014-11-01 07:00:00 +0000
endOfMonth: 2014-12-01 07:59:59 +0000
interval: 2595600.000000
```

As you can see, the *endOfMonth* is incorrect; it should be 2014-11-30... what is wrong with the code? (it isn't mine, I found it on SO)

I changed the timeZone property of "cal," but still got the same log message.

Comment: The dates are the start end of of the month in your current time zone, but are being displayed in UTC by NSLog. Is the problem that you wanted the start/end of the month in UTC? Or is the problem that you wanted start/end of month in local time zone and wish it just displayed you these dates in the local timeline rather than UTC? Bottom line, what's the business need of these two date fields?

Answer (score 1):

`startOfMonth` prints incorrectly also.

The times are actually correct, however when you print them, it prints with your timezone.

Printing a date will print that date in the UTC timezone. You can print it in your set timezone like this:

```
NSLog(@"\n\nstartOfMonth: %@\nendOfMonth: %@\ninterval: %d",[startOfMonth descriptionWithLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]], [endOfMonth descriptionWithLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]], (int)interval);
```

To update the dates instead, try this:

```
[cal rangeOfUnit:NSMonthCalendarUnit startDate:&startOfMonth interval:&interval forDate:now];
NSTimeInterval timeZoneOffset = [[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] secondsFromGMT];
startOfMonth = [startOfMonth dateByAddingTimeInterval:timeZoneOffset];
endOfMonth = [startOfMonth dateByAddingTimeInterval:interval-1];
NSLog(@"\n\nstartOfMonth: %@\nendOfMonth: %@\ninterval: %d",startOfMonth, endOfMonth, (int)interval);
```

Changing the calendar works also:

```
cal.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"];
[cal rangeOfUnit:NSMonthCalendarUnit startDate:&startOfMonth interval:&interval forDate:now];
```

Comment: OK... I fixed it like so, and it made no difference:

        NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
        NSTimeZone *zone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"PST"];
        [calendar setTimeZone:zone];

Comment: No, that won't work... I didn't show it, but the dates are used in a NSPredicate that searches for records between the start and end dates.  Sorry for leaving that out.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is convert from UTC to the time zone of interest.

You'll want to set the timeZone property of your calendar to the time zone you want to use. The following code, which comes from [the Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtTimeZones.html), will set the time zone to Central Daylight Time:

```
[gregorian setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"CDT"]];
```

Comment: Changing or setting the timezone makes no difference; the start date is correct, the end date still shows December 1, 2014

Answer (score 0):

here i can post you code what you exectly want..

```
-(NSMutableDictionary *)getMonthsStartAndEndDatesFromDate:(NSDate *)date
{

    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

    NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:( NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit) fromDate:date];
    components.day = 1;

    NSDate *startDate = [[gregorian dateFromComponents:components] dateByAddingTimeInterval:0];


    NSDateComponents *components1=[gregorian components:NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
    //NSEraCalendarUnit |
    NSInteger month=[components1 month];
    NSInteger year=[components1 year];

    if (month==12)
    {
        [components1 setYear:year+1];
        [components1 setMonth:1];
    }
    else {
        [components1 setMonth:month+1];
    }
    [components1 setDay:0];

    NSDate *endDate =[[gregorian dateFromComponents:components1] dateByAddingTimeInterval:0];


    NSMutableDictionary *dictTemp = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z"];

    startDate = [self dateFromDate:startDate WithHour:0 minute:0 second:01];
    endDate =[self dateFromDate:endDate WithHour:23 minute:59 second:59];


    NSString *StrHour = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:startDate];
    NSString *strMin = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:endDate];


    [dictTemp setObject:StrHour forKey:@"StartDate"];
    [dictTemp setObject:strMin forKey:@"EndDate"];

    return dictTemp;

}
-(NSDate *) dateFromDate:(NSDate *)date
                WithHour:(NSInteger)hour
                  minute:(NSInteger)minute
                  second:(NSInteger)second
{
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components: NSYearCalendarUnit|
                                    NSMonthCalendarUnit|
                                    NSDayCalendarUnit
                                               fromDate:date];
    [components setHour:hour];
    [components setMinute:minute];
    [components setSecond:second];
    NSDate *newDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
    return newDate;
}
```

`[self getMonthsStartAndEndDatesFromDate:[NSDate new]];`

This Method return start and end date 
like this

EndDate = "2014-11-30 23:59:59 GMT+5:30";
 StartDate = "2014-11-01 00:01:00 GMT+5:30";

So may this will help you lot..